# How to plot values from a List with Matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

Beginner here! I have a list that contains single values that rapprensent the mean cover distance by an animal for each month of the year.

```
mean = [7.51790364988932, 26.54709179011294, 29.65764360621555, 136.671273129226, 126.13064622076125, 25.366008757314532, 4.663780674841924, 3.7616067897445777, 4.330291751722638, 25.038066596104834, 92.81906072064585, 45.74368656241264]
```

I have also a supplementary list with the Standard Deviation of the mean:

```
StDev = [5.927150675222632, 15.59253255407175, 16.312448356657924, 81.31314415973934, 41.580975203922236, 11.480435976180836, 2.9712310351842786, 1.9313303794907384, 2.063154699821021, 30.746712593757756, 44.5391819737211, 11.590817409187078]
```

I would plot such values with mathplotlib to create a graphic similar to the example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to extract the values of the list to create the plot.

Comment: `plt.errorbar(x, mean, StDev)` where `x = range(len(mean))`?